# Select where value difference between (columnA and columnB) > 0,10

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to compare two columns. I want select only column where value difference between two columns > 0,10.

Example:

```
Select ColumnA from Table1 where CoLumnA <> ColumnB > 0,10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM Table1
WHERE ColumnA <> ColumnB 
AND ABS(ColumnA - ColumnB) BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

Details on `ABS()` and `BETWEEN` can be found here:

- [`ABS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx)
- [`BETWEEN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the edit [Abhay Chauhan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7221479/abhay-chauhan), I missed the requirement that we don't want records where ColumnA = ColumnB.

Comment: Why do i need abs? can i do it without abs?Example select column A where  (ColumnA-ColumnB) between -0.10 and 0.10???

Comment: @DIMITRIS yes you could, but you would need a `CASE` statement or use `MAX` or `MIN` or similar to achieve the same thing, because we don't know which is larger out of the values in `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` (do we?). Why do you not want to use `ABS()`?

Comment: I dont have problem i just ask for learning more. But also i set expression (-) and (+) where (columnA - ColumnB) between    -0.1   and    0.1 so no point if ColumnA or ColumnB is larger. Thanks for the answers

Comment: @DIMITRIS yes, that's also a valid way to achieve the same result I guess, so in the example in my answer, you could equally do `ColumnA - ColumnB BETWEEN -10 AND 10`.